# Create a Column that returns "Yes" if the answer to 2 previous columns match

Tags: sql, matching

I want to bring a column into my SQL query using SQL Server to look at the previous 2 columns and if the answers match, return "yes" and if not return "no"

EG in the below query I need the last column to state if Answer 1 and Answer 2 match

```
Select Name
       ,Answer 1
       ,Answer 2
       ,???   AS [do Answer 1 & 2 match]
```

in the above example where I have put ??? is where I am looking for how to code it to reflect if the previous 2 answers match

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: `answer_1 = answer_2`?

Comment: Not clear about your question. Can you provide sample data and expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want a `case` expression?

```
(case when answer1 = answer2 then 1 else 0 end) as match_1_2_flag
```

Comment: The 2 columns that I need to check if the answers match are generated from the code: 
,MAX(CASE WHEN FA.DIm_assessment_template_question_ID  = '68562' THEN answer END) AS [Chronology Compliance Grade (Auditor)]
,MAX(CASE WHEN FA.DIm_assessment_template_question_ID  = '68606' THEN answer END) AS [Chronology Compliance Grade (Moderator)]
So I need the matching query to cross reference these 2 outputs

Answer (score 0):

Is this what are you expecting?

```
Select Name
     ,Answer 1
     ,Answer 2
,case when Answer 1 = Answer 2 then 'Yes' else 'No' end from table_name;
```